# How to deallocate a portion of a continuous memory block?

Tags: c++, memory-management

let's assume I have a structure `MyStruct` and i want to allocate a "big" chunk of memory like this:

```
std::size_t memory_chunk_1_size = 10;
MyStruct * memory_chunk_1 = reinterpret_cast <MyStruct *> (new char[memory_chunk_1_size * sizeof(MyStruct)]);
```

and because of the "arbitrary reasons" I would like to "split" this chunk of memory into two smaller chunks without; moving data, resizing the "dynamic array", deallocating/allocating/reallocating memory, etc.

so I am doing this:

```
std::size_t memory_chunk_2_size = 5;              // to remember how many elements there are in this chunk;
MyStruct * memory_chunk_2 = &memory_chunk_1[5];   // points to the 6th element of memory_chunk_1;

memory_chunk_1_size = 5;                          // to remember how many elements there are in this chunk;
memory_chunk_1 = memory_chunk_1;                  // nothing changes still points to the 1st element.
```

Unfortunately, when I try to deallocate the memory, I'm encountering an error:

```
// release memory from the 2nd chunk
for (int i = 0; i < memory_chunk_2_size ; i++)
{
    memory_chunk_2[i].~MyStruct();
}
delete[] reinterpret_cast <char *> (memory_chunk_2); // deallocates memory from both "memory_chunk_2" and "memory_chunk_1"

// release memory from the 1st chunk
for (int i = 0; i < memory_chunk_1_size ; i++)
{
    memory_chunk_1[i].~MyStruct();                   // Throws exception.
}
delete[] reinterpret_cast <char *> (memory_chunk_1); // Throws exception. This part of the memory was already dealocated.
```

**How can I delete only a selected number of elements (to solve this error)?**

Compilable example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct MyStruct
{
    int first;
    int * second;

    void print()
    {
        cout << "- first:  " <<  first  << endl;
        cout << "- second: " << *second << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    MyStruct() :
        first(-1), second(new int(-1))
    {
        cout << "constructor #1" << endl;
        print();
    }

    MyStruct(int ini_first, int ini_second) :
        first(ini_first), second(new int(ini_second))
    {
        cout << "constructor #2" << endl;
        print();
    }

    ~MyStruct()
    {
        cout << "destructor" << endl;
        print();

        delete second;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // memory chunk #1:
    std::size_t memory_chunk_1_size = 10;
    MyStruct * memory_chunk_1 = reinterpret_cast <MyStruct *> (new char[memory_chunk_1_size * sizeof(MyStruct)]);

    // initialize:
    for (int i = 0; i < memory_chunk_1_size; i++)
    {
        new (&memory_chunk_1[i]) MyStruct(i,i);
    }

    // ...
    // Somewhere here I decided I want to have two smaller chunks of memory instead of one big,
    // but i don't want to move data nor reallocate the memory:

    std::size_t memory_chunk_2_size = 5;              // to remember how many elements there are in this chunk;
    MyStruct * memory_chunk_2 = &memory_chunk_1[5];   // points to the 6th element of memory_chunk_1;

    memory_chunk_1_size = 5;                          // to remember how many elements there are in this chunk;
    memory_chunk_1 = memory_chunk_1;                  // nothing changes still points to the 1st element.

    // ... 
    // some time later i want to free memory:

    // release memory from the 2nd chunk
    for (int i = 0; i < memory_chunk_2_size ; i++)
    {
        memory_chunk_2[i].~MyStruct();
    }
    delete[] reinterpret_cast <char *> (memory_chunk_2); // deallocates memory from both "memory_chunk_2" and "memory_chunk_1"

    // release memory from the 1st chunk
    for (int i = 0; i < memory_chunk_1_size ; i++)
    {
        memory_chunk_1[i].~MyStruct();                   // Throws exception.
    }
    delete[] reinterpret_cast <char *> (memory_chunk_1); // Throws exception. This part of the memory was already dealocated.

    // exit:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***How can I delete only a selected number of elements*** You can't. You can only delete the entire allocation not part of it.

Comment: Internally the Operating System has a pair {begin, size} for every allocation. You can't modify them, except deallocating the whole chunk.

Comment: You have to own the whole chunk until you give it all back. So I guess  you have to do is keep your own housekeeping which parts are allocated etc...

Comment: It seems that you need to use std::malloc/std::realloc instead of operator new

Comment: @Victor I don't really believe that would help more.

Comment: Maybe you can think of allocating a few contiguous chunks with an unique size, then will be able to desallocate them individually.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use your own allocator. Make an allocator that obtains a large pool of memory and virtually allocates/deallocates small chunks of it. This won't help you if your goal is to actually free memory early, but it will help you if you expect to reuse those chunks yourself for other purposes.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ In fact in most cases it will. Since memory allocator (HeapAlloc/HeapRealloc, pdmalloc, jemalloc etc) in most cases will stay data in place, and shrink block metadata.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the longer I think about this problem the more I am convinced that this is the solution to go. However won't that be a "step back"? I mean it's more like creating a sophisticated piece of software just to use this software to implement something far less sophisticated.

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 If you want to do something complicated, sometimes the solution will take a lot of work.  In this situation, it depends on your allocation requirements. A simple and naive allocator is actually relatively simple to implement. Consider making your allocator compatible with [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) for maximum flexibility and reusability. Since c++17, `std::allocator` just has to provide `allocate`, `deallocate`, a few type alias, a few constructors and the equality operators.

Comment: I see another problem with the code, which is that alignment constraints of `MyStruct` are not necessarily taken into account.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of selective deallocation is not supported by the C++ programming language, and is probably never going to be supported.

If you intend to deallocate individual portions of memory, those individual portions need to be individually allocated in the first place.

It is *possible* that a specific OS or platform might support this kind of behavior, but it would be with OS-specific system calls, not through C++ standard language syntax.

Comment: `specific OS` i suppose you mean C/C++ standard library and it's memory allocator i.e. malloc and operator new. OS system calls (at least in case of Windows VirtualAlloc and Unix brk/sbrk/mmap )  able to allocate virtual memory in pages. I.e. minimal block is something about 4k. C library malloc, allocates such blocks and returning smaller chunks.

Comment: @VictorGubin I'm thinking that there's nothing stopping an OS from permitting itemized deallocations, except for the difficulty/inefficiency of implementing such a system. So there may hypothetically be an OS that has calls like `char* mem = my_os_allocate(4096); my_os_deallocate(mem + 2048, 1024);` which leave the first 2048 bytes and the last 1024 bytes as valid memory, but the bytes between `mem+2048` and `mem+3072` is returned to the OS. I don't personally know of any such system, and C++ doesn't acknowledge such a system in its language, but it's theoretically possible.

Comment: in most cases even if you call to delete []/delete or std::free virtual memory actually will not be returned to operating system back, it will be saved for latter usage (next calls to std::malloc/operator new). Some memory allocators like jemalloc for example, have a background garbage collector thread, which scanning memory in a schedule and returns empty virtual memory regions, not used for a long time, back to system.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocated with malloc or new cannot be partially deallocate. Many heaps use bins of different sized allocations for performance and to prevent fragmentation so allowing partial frees would make such a strategy impossible.

That of course does not prevent you writing your own allocator.

Comment: `with malloc` in fact it can (off cause no any guaranty for returning memory back for OS, or data will stay where it was). See [realloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc) `a) expanding or contracting the existing area pointed to by ptr, if possible. The contents of the area remain unchanged up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. If the area is expanded, the contents of the new part of the array are undefined. `

Answer (score 1):

Let's be honest: this is a very bad practice ! Trying to cast `new` and `delete` and in addition call yourself destructor between the two is an evidence of low-level manual memory management.

**Alternatives**

The proper way to manage dynamic memory structures in contiguous blocks in C++ is to use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of manual arrays or manual memory management, and let the library proceed.  You can [`resize()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) a vector to delete the unneeded elements. You can [`shrink_to_fit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/) to say that you no longer need the extra free capacity, although it's not guaranteed that unneeded memory is released.

The use of C memory allocation functions and in particular [`realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) is to be avoided, as it is very error prone, and it works only with [trivially copiable objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable).

**Edit: Your own container**

If you want to implement your own special container and must allows this kind of dynamic behaviour, due to unusual special constraints, then you should consider writing your own memory management function that would manage a kind of "private heap".

Heap management is often implement via a [linked list of free chunks](http://dysphoria.net/OperatingSystems1/4_allocation_list.html).
One strategy could be to allocate a new chunk when there's no sufficient contiguous memory left in your private heap.  You could then offer a more permissive `myfree()` function that reinserts a freed or partially freed chunk into that linked list.  Of course, this requires to iterate through the linked list to find if the released memory is contiguous to any other chunk of free memory in the private heap, and merge the blocks if adjacent.

I see that `MyStruct` is very small.  Another approach could then be to write a special allocation function optimised for small fixed size blocks.  There is an example in [Loki's small object library](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00632.html) that is described in depth in "[Modern C++ Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design)".

Finally, you could perhaps have a look at the [Pool library of Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html), which also offers a [chunk based approach](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/pooling.html).

Comment: I see what you mean, but `std::vector` will not do the trick for me. Like I said it is critical for me **NOT** to move data or re-allocate memory. The thing is I am writing my own container (like a hybrid between `std::list` and `std::vector`) **that guarantees the data will not be moved** (if I create a pointer to an element, that pointer will stay valid to the end of "time"). The sheer fact that I want to "split" existing block of memory is because I want to implement `std::vector::insert()`-like function that will "update" the metadata of the memory the container owns.

Comment: That's why I need a low-level memory management. And yes you are right, my current implementation is "bad" and that's why I asked for the help of this great community, to do it right. The best suited for meidea I heard up until now is to create my own memory manager that will "virtually" allocate and deallocate memory

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I could think of by means of standard c++ would follow this idiomatic code:

```
std::vector<int> v1(1000);
auto block_start = v1.begin() + 400;
auto block_end = v1.begin() + 500;
std::vector<int> v2(block_start,block_end);
v1.erase(block_start,block_end);
v1.shrink_to_fit();
```

If a compiler is intelligent enough to translate such pattern to the most efficient low level OS and CPU memory management operations, is an implementation detail.

Here's the [working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/906e218a21a42e6b).